# python recursion is not working as expected

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

I'm new to coding and trying to teach myself about recursion by building a very simple function that calls itself.  However my code is behaving slightly differently to how I was expecting:

## get user input number that must not be greater than 50

```
def getinput():
  input = int(raw_input("type number under 50 >>> "))
  if input < 50:
    return input
  else:
    print input, "no, must be under 50"
    getinput()

print getinput()
```

This results in the following behavior:

## This bit as expected

C:\Python27>python recur.py

type number under 50 >>> 23

23

## This bit unexpected

C:\Python27>python recur.py

type number under 50 >>> 63

63 no, must be under 50

type number under 50 >>> 23

None

My question is, why is the last line "None", and not 23?  My code seems to correctly call the function again if the user inputs a number 50 or greater, but why doesn't the second call return 23 (the same as the initial output)?

Any advice much appreciated

Comment: You need to `return` the function call, else what is your original function going to return in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return the result of the getInput() if the number is greater than 50

```
def getinput():
input = int(raw_input("type number under 50 >>> "))
  if input < 50:
    return input
  else:
    print input, "no, must be under 50"
    return getinput() 

print getinput()
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `return` in the else condition. The following code should work:

```
def getinput():
  input = int(raw_input("type number under 50 >>> "))
  if input < 50:
    return input
  else:
    print input, "no, must be under 50"
    return getinput()

print getinput()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case your function will return `input`

```
if input < 50:
    return input
```

You are using recursion, so it is just like a stack at the end all the return values will come back to the function which was called. When the condition `if input < 50` not satisfied it will return **None** and you are using `print(getinput())`.

```
| 23  |
| 63  | -> None
 -----
```

That's just my understanding about recursion.

so when the value is greater than 50, do return a value instead of None to the function back.

```
return getinput()
```

Also please use different variable names instead of `input`.